# JAXB: two versions of XSD, one object model

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, versioning

I have two versions of an XSD Schema. The XSDs are very similar, although the XML namespace is different (the xml namespace is used for versioning). I would like to unmarshall the two versions using the same object model. JAXB is used to generate the object model.

Is there an easy way to read two slightly different XML models into the same object model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard JAXB can't do this, although some implementations may have proprietary workarounds.

What you could try is to read the document into a DOM model (i.e. org.w3c.dom.Document), programmatically set the namespace URI of the DOM to match the one in the JAXB class model, and then unmarshal the DOM into JAXB (using `Unmarshaller.unmarshall(document)`.  The performance of this will suck, but that may not matter for you.

As an aide, have a look at [this PDF](http://www.xfront.com/Versioning.pdf) describing best practices for versioning schemas (hint: changing the namespace URI is not best practice...)

Comment: Nice link.  A faster filtering approach could be based on Stax or Sax, rather than DOM.

Comment: @Ed: Aye, true. More effort to string together, but probably a better solution.

Comment: This might be one case where SAX would be simplest, as it'd be quite easy to add filter that converts namespace declarations on the fly.

Comment: I ended up using this approach, with a DOM model. Since there are a few more differences between versions than just the namespace, using DOM was easier than SAX.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JAXB implementation (Metro, MOXy, JaxMe, etc) with a StAX parser (RI, Woodstox, etc) to solve this issue.  Assuming that aside from names that your documents are backwards compatible you can map your object model to the newest schema.  Then you will trick your JAXB implementation to thinking that all versions of the document are using that namespace.  The trick is to use a [`StreamReaderDelegate`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html) from the StAX API.

**For a Similar Example**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html